# How to delete property from relationship in Memgraph?

Tags: memgraphdb, opencypher

I've came across two possible solutions for deleting a property from all nodes:

First method is to set it to null: `MATCH (n:name) SET n.age = NULL`

Second method is to remove property.

```
MATCH (n:name)
REMOVE n.age
RETURN n;
```

In both cases the end result seems the same to me.

Can the value of a property in a relationship be set to `null` and be deleted in that way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that is officially supported by [openCypher](https://opencypher.org/).

Here is an excerpt from the latest (version 9) openCypher language reference:

> **Remove a property**
>
> Normally you remove a property by using REMOVE, but it’s sometimes
> handy to do it using the SET command. One example is if the property
> comes from a parameter.
>
> *Query*
>
> ```
> MATCH (n {name: 'Andres'})
> SET n.name = NULL
> RETURN n
> ```
>
> The node is returned by the query, and the name property is now missing.